# Why am I showing as though I am 33% damaged?

Tags: eve-online

I have just finished putting modules on this new ship, and upon undocking I am showing as though I have taken 33% damage to my shields, armour and hull - as per the screenshot below;

[image]

As you can see, the tooltips show that I am indeed at 100%, yet the graphical representation of this indicates otherwise. I have no modules that decrease the strength of my hull, armour or shields.

Why am I showing as though I am 33% damaged?

Comment: i'm not sure since i haven't played eve in ages but couldnt it be something to do with not having enough power ?

Comment: Are you in a fleet with someone?

Comment: No to both - I am not in a fleet at the moment and I'm not low on power

Comment: Did this happen on Tranquility ?
Normally any damage (even from a puny rat) will set your meters to the correct level.

Comment: yes this is on live

Comment: This is very likely a bug. Press F12 to send a good ol' Bug Report... Maybe tell them if the apparent damage went away when your took a hit so they know if it was purely the reading that was faulty of if you took undeserved damage.

Comment: aye, looks like a visual bug, especially if it tells you you have full shields.

Comment: See this forum post: https://forums.eveonline.com/default.aspx?g=posts&m=2506727#post2506727

Comment: maybe your 'fake being damaged' system is working so well, it's even fooling you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug, [as reported on the EVE Online forums](https://forums.eveonline.com/default.aspx?g=posts&m=2495001#post2495001), I've had it happen a few times, the fix is to dock and undock again as it's **only** a display issue.

Comment: I would like to stress that this is a graphical error. Your ship is not damaged, in fact as soon as one of the three takes damage, it will move up to the new percentage, and display correctly from then on.

Comment: Also, one can open the planet management window to clear this bug. Although that's also how you can duplicate this bug.